# I got "System.TypeLoadException" Error 500 after running .net 4.7 old project

Tags: c#, .net, mono, rider

I got this error after I run our old project which is using .net version 4.7 and I don't have any idea because I'm just starting learning this language and I want to run it on my machine locally. See image below for reference:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Mono is not .NET Framework, so the exception is expected. Please also note that Mono is going away https://halfblood.pro/the-end-of-mono/ To learn C# and .NET on a non-Windows machine, use .NET Core https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/whats-new/dotnet-6

Comment: If I remove mono on my project is it possible to run? This is very old project that's why it has mono.

Comment: Old projects can only be migrated to .NET Core, and you shouldn't expect Mono to be there for ever.

Answer (score -1):

It's fine now. I use correct mono framework version which is old one.